# How to calculate storage space for each user on Rails app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, saas

I'm working on a SaaS application. Each user will buy a plan on this application and he will be given a certain amount of storage corresponding to amount of information on the app. For example, the Free user will get 1GB free storage, the Basic user will get 5GB storage.

Currently, all information are stored in MySQL database and it is just plain text without any binary data on disk such as images or videos.

Let's imaging Gmail without attachment as an example of this application.

How can I implement this function on my application? Do we need a method that somehow calculates the amount of info contains in database for a specific user and does some validation on that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a running tally of how much space each user has consumed, which is then updated every time a write is made against their quota. Continually computing it is not going to be very efficient.